# How do I debug my Xamarin.ios Share Extension on iOS device with Photos (or other Apps) using Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019, share-extension

I have developed a Xamarin App (for iOS & Android) and added an iOS Share Extension project to it. All works fine in that I can deploy and debug both the Container App and the Share Extension on my device (iPad). When I launch the Visual Studio 2019 debugger (when my Extension project is selected), it auto-launches Safari. So far, I have tested my code with Safari and all works fine. As my extension supports multiple types of items (images, document, URL, etc.), I want to now debug sharing of images and other things. How do I do this so that Safari is not auto-launched and the debugger should wait until I start my Share Extension (using any of the applicable Apps)?

I'm using the latest updates for Visual Studio 2019 (as of this writing).

Given I can run/debug the (container) App and the Share Extension fine, I believe my setup, profiles, etc. is all okay.

Ideally, I want to be able to put breakpoints in my code and debug the Share Extension when sharing an image, Word document and so on.

Any advise or pointing in the right direction will be much appreciated.

My Share Extension info.plist section for the items supported is as follows:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointName</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainStoryboard</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the XCode->Instruments app? You should be able to read everything that's happening on your phone

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Saamer. I did not use a Mac (MacBook Pro in this case) before this project. So you will have to be patient as I find my way around. Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Instruments, this displays a lot of tools. At the top of this window, for 'Choose a profiling template for' I selected my iPad, then my Extension under 'App Extension' & when the extension is running. But then what do I choose? The listed tools seem to target specific thins. Where do I get a general activity?

Comment: I also looked at, Xcode -> Window -> Devices and simulators, then my iPad -> Open Console. This spews out tons of data relating to all sorts. How can I filter it for just my Extension? I couldn't find a way to do this as clicking on the column heading doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: I am using Xcode ver. 10.2.1. All things are up to date as far as I know - both on Windows Visual Studio, Windows 10, MacBook, Xcode, Xamarin, etc.

Comment: Hey Yousef that's good that you were able to launch the debug console. Help me understand, what all are you trying to do? So the user taps on the Share button and you want to be able to open the file in the right app? What kind of file extensions are there? Are you using a device or the emulator for debugging?

Comment: Thanks Saamer. I'm developing a Xamarin App, with a Share Extension. At present this is all for iOS only and I'm only using the Share Extension. The idea is, for supported files (text, URL, image, word document, etc. - see above info.plist for entire list), the user should be able to share/upload the content to our web server. We use Azure blob service to store what the user upload. Again, all this works as expected for URL & text sharing. I can test/debug this using Safari. Wanted the ability to debug in Visual Studio with Photos (and other) Apps. I can't at present. I'm using an iPad.

Comment: So far, I'm using old style debugging - I have added a lot of console output messages through out my App to debug uploading an image using the Photos App and my Share Extension. I see the output in the Console window on Mac but as you know, it is VERY tedious. Was after a more 'elegant' solution to debug. Oh well, may be it is not possible (even in 2019!).

Comment: I'm afraid console output is the only way for debugging currently.